# is there any way to get jenkins build number using jenkins-cli

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have builds numbered 1, 2, 3 & 4 for my job named TEST_JOB. With jenkins-cli.jar, am planning to execute a command where I can get build numbers of my TEST_JOB.

Have tried using cli commands such as console (which prints the outputs console of the last build/ current build) & build (which runs the job) but neither of which returns a build number.

Am planning to do this via command prompt. Any idea as to how should I proceed?

Answer (score -1):

Why using Jenkins-cli jar? I mean you can do it using that but I think the better option is to access job/build metadata using Jenkins API.

How to get started with Jenkins API? you can see job metadata in JSON/XML format in the following URL:
JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/api/json
JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/api/xml

In the job level, you can see there details as: parameters, builds list and more
In the build level, you can see there details as: who started the build, parameters, duration, result

And then from code perspective, you can access JSON/XML using curl command or wrap it with python code.

Comment: am accessing jenkins via juju api. For which am using jenkins-cli which best suits my requirement.

Comment: ok cool :) so which information exactly do you need from job ? latest build number ?

Comment: Am only looking to display 5 latest builds. But latest build 'll also do.